# React Native Firebase: no custom sound, no vibration

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I try to implement feature when notification arrives, the phone should vibrate and play some kind of ringing sound.

How ever, i could only play phone's default notification sound.

The versions I'm using:

```
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.1",
```

The code:

First I create the channel

```
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
                'my_channel_id', 
                'My channel', 
                firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
            )
            .setDescription('My Notif')
            .setSound("mysound.mp3")
      .setVibrationPattern([400, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000]) 
            .setLockScreenVisibility(firebase.notifications.Android.Visibility.Public)

        this.channel.enableVibration(true);

        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
```

Then later I create the notificaiton

```
const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                .setNotificationId('notificationId')
                .setTitle('Some notification')
                .setBody('Some body')

                notification.android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
                notification.android.setLargeIcon('ic_launcher');
                notification.android.setChannelId('my_channel_id');

                notification.android.addAction(new firebase.notifications.Android.Action("answer", "ic_launcher", "Open"))

                notification.android.setColorized(true)
                notification.android.setColor('#00a8ff')
                notification.android.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                notification.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)
                notification.android.setVibrate([400, 800, 600, 800, 800, 800, 1000]);

                firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
```

Notification is displayed with default sound. The mp3 file is located at /android/app/src/main/res/raw/. It plays always the default notification "bling" sound.

No errors are shown in console.

adb logcat says something like this but I'm not sure are they related to this:

> 02-22 21:20:30.848  4916  4916 D EdgeLightingManager:
>   showForNotification : isInteractive=true, isHeadUp=true, color=0, sbn
>   = StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.my user=UserHandle{0} id=788267878 tag=null key=0|com.my|788267878|null|10188:
>   Notification(channel=my_channel_id pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=null
>   sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x8 color=0xff00a8ff actions=1 number=0
>   vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))

These settings are in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I have checked phone settings, all sounds are on and vibrations enabled.

So, *should* my code work? Thank you!

btw, I hear no sound in iOS neither but there I'm not using firebase :)

Comment: hey, have you added sound and vibration in your notification. I need help on this issue.

Comment: @himanshu Added to where? Thanks

Comment: @iiro are u solve it?

Comment: Did anybody solves this issue.? I am still looking for solution.

Answer (score 2):

For about the vibration, this works for me

```
.android.setVibrate([1000, 1000])
.android.setDefaults([firebase.notifications.Android.Defaults.Vibrate])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may be that you are not re-assigning the notification object. For example:

```
notification = notification.android.setVibrate([300]);
```

Otherwise you are just setting it on a new object that is never used.